# Dagger 2 lazy initialize map entries

Tags: java, dagger-2, lazy-initialization

I have a Dagger module and component defined as below. I want to create the resources in the module only when they are being fetched from the map and not when the service comes up. I played around using Lazy but not sure how to achieve this.

```
@Module
public abstract class ExpensiveObjectModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @UniqueKey(Key.A)
    static ExpensiveObject provideKeyAExpensiveObject() {
        return new ExpensiveObject(Key.A);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @UniqueKey(Key.B)
    static ExpensiveObject provideKeyBExpensiveObject() {
        return new ExpensiveObject(Key.B);
    }
}
```

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = {
        ExpensiveObjectModule.class
})
public interface HandlerComponent {
    Map<Key, ExpensiveObject> getExpensiveObjectByKey();

}
```

```
handlerComponent.getExpensiveObjectByKey().get(key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you can inject `A` you can also inject `Provider<A>`, so instead of having a `Map<K, A>` you can have a `Map<K, Provider<A>>`. The same would probably work with Lazy, but a Provider will respect whatever scope something has, while Lazy would always cache it.

So you could just return the map like this:

```
Map<Key, Provider<ExpensiveObject>> getExpensiveObjectByKey();
```

---

A minimal example (but in Kotlin) looks like this:

```kotlin
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class Key(val value: String)

@Module
object ModFoo {

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @Key("foo")
    fun foo(): Any = "Foo"

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @Key("bar")
    fun bar(): Any = 3
}

@Component(modules = [ModFoo::class])
interface Foo {
    val foo: Map<String, Any>
    val fooProviders: Map<String, Provider<Any>>
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but Dagger complains that there is no @Provides-method that provides Provider<ExpensiveObject>. How can I return Provider<ExpensiveObject> instead of new ExpensiveObject(Key.B)?

Comment: @SairamSankaran not sure what you're doing, but I included a small sample for reference

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck up on Lazy<T> but apparently its not possible - https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1630

With Provider<T> and @Singleton I am able to achieve the desired effect of lazily instantiating them as well as one copy per instance